# Flutter app auto detect a hyperlink and open it by tapping

Tags: flutter, url

So i try to create a note app using flutter. What i am trying to do is when the user saves a url on a note, the app automatically recognises the URL and then the user can open it on the browser without having to copy and paste. Just by tapping on it. Any ideas ???

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution....i used flutter_linkify and url_launcher....thanks anyway for anyone who was going to  or will be posting any help !!